# Measure function time execution without modification code

Tags: linux, performance, compiler-construction, time, measurement

I have found some piece of code (function) in library which could be improved by the optimization of compiler (as the main idea - to find good stuff to go deep into compilers). And I want to automate measurement of time execution of this function by script. As it's low-level function in library and get arguments it's difficult to extract this one. **Thus I want to find out the way of measurement exactly this function (precise CPU time) without library/application/environment modifications**. Have you any ideas how to achieve that?

I could write wrapper but I'll need in near future much more applications for performance testing and I think to write wrapper for every one is very ugly.

P.S.: My code will run on ARM (armv7el) architecture, which has some kind of "Performance Monitor Control" registers. I have learned about "perf" in linux kernel. But don't know is it what I need?

Comment: You should be able to use any code profiler compatible with your programming language - this is exactly the kind of problem they are made to solve.

Comment: Do you have the source code of the profiled library? What compiler are you using? Do you use `gprof` or `oprofile` ?

Comment: Doesn't matter what kind of profiler to use. But important do not recompiler application and to get real values of time execution of function. Yes, I have source code of profiled application (library).

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you have access to the source code of the function you want to profile or improve, i.e. if you are able to recompile the considered library.

If you are using a recent GCC (that is 4.6 at least) on a recent Linux system, you could use profilers like `gprof` (assuming you are able to recompile the library) or better [`oprofile`](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/) (which you could use without recompiling), and you could customize GCC for your needs.

Be aware that like any measurements, profiling may alter the observed phenomenon.

If you are considering customizing the GCC compiler for optimization purposes, consider making a GCC plugin, or better yet, a [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension, for that purpose (MELT is a high-level domain specific language to extend GCC). You could also customize GCC (with MELT) for your own specific profiling purposes.

Comment: Thanks, but know important even not how to change compiler. Important how to measure execution of some stuff (function), for example before and after applying my optimization, without altering the observed phenomenon - it is important. If I add -gp (gprof) and profile, I can't be sure that gprof didn't change measurement time - as it changes assembler and add additional code. I need to measure exactly compiled binary. I suggest that it is done by using specific hardware registers - by they these features should be applied in profile/measurement tool.